# Is there a way to detect whether my Android TV remote has a microphone or not?

Tags: android, android-tv

I have an Android TV app that I'm integrating a Speech Recognizer into. Only today did I find out that the Android TV supports the Remote microphone.

Detecting whether the device has a microphone is easy enough using `requireActivity().packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_MICROPHONE)`, but I don't think it accounts for remote microphones.

My question is whether it's possible to detect whether the remote I'm using has a Microphone or not, so that I can display the "No Audio Signals" error if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The way I will do is to use AudioRecord then call the function of `startRecording()` and after that, you should check recorder's state by invoking `getRecordingState()`. If the recording was started successfully, it proves that there is a microphone attached to the device regardless of internal or external. The function will return 3 (AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) otherwise it will return 1 (AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)

Below is the code for Kotlin :

```
private fun checkMicAvailability(audioRecord: AudioRecord): Boolean {
    audioRecord.startRecording()
    val micCheckAvailability= audioRecord.recordingState == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING
    audioRecord.stop()
    audioRecord.release()
    return micCheckAvailability
}
```

Do note that you must create it with the AudioRecord constructor. You can have a look at [Audio Recorder Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord)

Comment: I wish there was a way that doesn't require me to use an `AudioRecord` instance for this purpose, since it seems to be overkill for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe u can have a look at `AudioDeviceInfo`. Hope this help

Comment: About `AudioDeviceInfo`, further investigation led me to the `AudioManager.getMicrophones()` method. Does it detect remote microphones too?

Comment: I believe in `AudioDeviceInfo` , there is this function `getAudioDevice()` which will return all the audio devices regardless of built-in mic, an external mic, or an audio interface attached to the device.